# Django app works on runserver, but fails on uwsgi

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, uwsgi

python3 manage.py runserver works fine, but running on nginx/uwsgi Django application doesn't work.
Uwsgi log:

```
binary reloading uWSGI...
chdir() to /
closing all non-uwsgi socket fds > 2 (max_fd = 1024)...
found fd 3 mapped to socket 0 (/home/nginx/pythonworld.sock)
running /usr/local/bin/uwsgi
[uWSGI] getting INI configuration from /home/dmitriym/new_pythonworld/pythonworld_wsgi.ini
*** Starting uWSGI 2.0.13.1 (64bit) on [Wed Jul 27 15:56:46 2016] ***
compiled with version: 4.8.4 on 27 July 2016 18:42:57
os: Linux-3.13.0-57-generic #95-Ubuntu SMP Fri Jun 19 09:28:15 UTC 2015
nodename: pythonworld.ru
machine: x86_64
clock source: unix
pcre jit disabled
detected number of CPU cores: 1
current working directory: /
detected binary path: /usr/local/bin/uwsgi
chdir() to /home/dmitriym/new_pythonworld/
your processes number limit is 7782
your memory page size is 4096 bytes
detected max file descriptor number: 1024
lock engine: pthread robust mutexes
thunder lock: disabled (you can enable it with --thunder-lock)
uwsgi socket 0 inherited UNIX address /home/nginx/pythonworld.sock fd 3
Python version: 3.4.3 (default, Oct 14 2015, 20:31:36)  [GCC 4.8.4]
*** Python threads support is disabled. You can enable it with --enable-threads ***
Python main interpreter initialized at 0x14ac400
your server socket listen backlog is limited to 100 connections
your mercy for graceful operations on workers is 60 seconds
mapped 145536 bytes (142 KB) for 1 cores
*** Operational MODE: single process ***
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 107, in create
    entry = module.default_app_config
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'default_app_config'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./new_pythonworld/wsgi.py", line 16, in <module>
    application = get_wsgi_application()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/django/core/wsgi.py", line 13, in get_wsgi_application
    django.setup()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/django/__init__.py", line 18, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 85, in populate
    app_config = AppConfig.create(entry)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 110, in create
    return cls(entry, module)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 40, in __init__
    self.path = self._path_from_module(app_module)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 73, in _path_from_module
    "with a 'path' class attribute." % (module, paths))
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: The app module <module 'bookshop' (namespace)> has multiple filesystem locations (['./bookshop', '/home/dmitriym/new_pythonworld/bookshop']); you must configure this app with an AppConfig subclass with a 'path' class attribute.
unable to load app 0 (mountpoint='') (callable not found or import error)
*** no app loaded. going in full dynamic mode ***
*** uWSGI is running in multiple interpreter mode ***
gracefully (RE)spawned uWSGI master process (pid: 1329)
spawned uWSGI worker 1 (pid: 1535, cores: 1)
```

I actually have **init**.py file in application directory.
And after setting apps.py and **init**.py

```
# apps.py
from django.apps import AppConfig

class MistypesConfig(AppConfig):
    name = 'bookshop'
    path = '/home/dmitriym/new_pythonworld/bookshop'

    def ready(self):
        pass


# __init__.py
default_app_config = 'bookshop.apps.MistypesConfig'
```

This problem still appears.

settings.py of project

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'mistypes',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'vacancy',
    'bookshop',
)

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',

    'django.middleware.gzip.GZipMiddleware',

    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',

    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
)

ROOT_URLCONF = 'new_pythonworld.urls'
APPEND_SLASH = False

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                #'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]


WSGI_APPLICATION = 'new_pythonworld.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}
```

pythonworld_wsgi.ini

```
[uwsgi]
# Django-related settings
# the base directory (full path)
chdir           = /home/dmitriym/new_pythonworld
# Djangos wsgi file
module          = new_pythonworld.wsgi
# process-related settings
# master
master          = true
# maximum number of worker processes
processes       = 1
#enable-threads  = true
#threads         = 4
# the socket (use the full path to be safe
socket          = /home/nginx/pythonworld.sock
# ... with appropriate permissions - may be needed
chmod-socket    = 664
# clear environment on exit
vacuum          = true
# pid file
pidfile         = /var/run/pythonworld.pid
# logging
logto           = /var/log/uwsgi/pythonworld.log
#stats           = /tmp/statsock
# uid and gid
uid             = nginx
gid             = www-data
```

And new_pythonworld/wsgi.py

```
"""
WSGI config for new_pythonworld project.

It exposes the WSGI callable as a module-level variable named ``application``.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/deployment/wsgi/
"""

import os

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application

os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "new_pythonworld.settings")

application = get_wsgi_application()
```

Comment: What's `new_pythonworld.wsgi.application`? What's in `pythonworld_wsgi.ini`?

Comment: Added new_pythonworld.wsgi.application and pythonworld_wsgi.ini

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was solved by changing permissions allowing read source code by uwsgi user.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error, just add an empty `__init__.py` file in all the apps.